# Unable to mark messages as read / unread

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When in the Careers site under messages, I click the checkbox for the message and then click "Mark Read" or "Mark Unread" nothing happens. Looking at the HTML for the elements, both items are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

There are checkboxes next to each item in your messages list. Once you check at least a single box, the buttons will become enabled.

EDIT:

It turns out this is a bug currently.  The disabled state for these buttons was messed up in a recent change. This will be fixed soon.

Comment: The broken part is on it's way out to prod now, the coloring of disabled buttons will happen sometime later.